# Where does GradleRunner put its build directory?

Tags: gradle, spock

I'm wanting to run a functional test that looks at the output of a Gradle plugin's task, which are a series of files.  I'm using [GradleRunner](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testkit/runner/GradleRunner.html), with tests that look like those in the [TestKit docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html), but run with Spock.

```
@Rule public final TemporaryFolder testProjectDir = new TemporaryFolder();
private File buildFile;

def setup() {
    buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile("build.gradle");
    buildFile << """
        plugins {id 'com.myplugin.id'}
    """
}

def "my plugin task creates myfile.txt inside build dir"() {
    given:

    when:

    def result = GradleRunner.create()
        .withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root)
        .withPluginClassPath()
        .withArguments("mytask")
        .build();

    then:
    result.task(":mytask").getOutcome() == SUCCESS
    new File(testProjectDir.root.absolutePath + "/build", "myfile.txt").exists()

}
```

I just don't see a `build` directory being created in my temporary directory.  Where are the build artifacts put?

Answer (score 1):

The `TemporaryFolder` folder rule creates a folder in your systems `TEMP` directory and deletes it as soon as the build finishes. If you want to inspect it, then the easiest way is to debug the test and just look at the content of `testProjectDir.root`.